# Job - creating programmatically

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am creating JobInstance programmatically

```
  JobInstance jobInstance = new JobInstance(rs.getLong(0),
                jobParameters, rs.getString(4));
```

I see examples like that. In spring-batch 3.0.7 JobInstance argument doesn't have jobParameters in parameter list in constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JobInstanceDao`

JobInstanceDao has createJobInstance and it takes `JobNames` and `JobParameters`.

Please refer to Spring docs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/dao/JobInstanceDao.html#createJobInstance-java.lang.String-org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters-

Comment: Thanks, we also used org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer.getJobInstances(String jobName, int start, int count) to get jobs with parameters and on some conditions we did restart this job with its parameters getJobLauncher().run(getJob(), jobParameters);  but since jobInstance is missing parameters when queried by getJobExplorer().getJobInstances(getJob().getName(), 0, 1) how could I do that? I am missing parameters... We did getJobLauncher().run(jobInstance, jobInstance.getJobParameters()); and today getJobParameters is removed from JobInstance

Comment: Job parameters now belong to the `JobExecution` object since "non-identifying" job parameters (introduced in Spring Batch 2.2.0) can be changed upon restart without forcing you to get a new `JobInstance`.